# STM32L47x GPIO register config

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, gpio

I'm trying to blink LED on my ST board B-L475E-IoT01A1 (basically STM32L475). LED2 is connected tp PB14. To enable GPIOB, I have to enable AHB2 bus (`RCC->AHB2ENR`).

[image]

Than I Configured GPIO port mode to General Purpose output mode (`GPIOB->MODE`)

[image]

than port output type (`GPIOB->OTYPER`)

[image]

than outputspeed (`GPIOB->OSPEEDR`)

[image]

than port pull-up/pull-down (`GPIOB->PUPDR`)

[image]

finally bit set and reset register (`GPIOB->PUPDR`)

[image]

I have attached my code below, I don't know what I have done wrong, my LED2 is not blinking.

```
#include "stm32l4xx_hal.h"

void Delay (uint32_t time)
{
    while (time--);  
}

int main()
{
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= (1<<1);
    GPIOB->MODER |= (1<<28);
    GPIOB->OTYPER &= ~(1<<14);
    GPIOB->OSPEEDR |= (1<<29);
    GPIOB->PUPDR &= ~((1<<28) | (1<<29));

  while(1)
  {
      GPIOB->BSRR = (1<<14);
      //for(int i =0; i<=50000; i++) ;
      Delay(10000000);
      GPIOB->BSRR = (1<<14+16);
      Delay(10000000);
      //for(int i =0; i<=50000; i++) ;
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does the LED turn on at all?  Are you sure about the operator precedence of `(1<<14+16)`?  Does the LED toggle when you single-step through the code with the debugger?  Does the `Delay()` function work as you intend and actually delay?

Comment: No, the LED do not turns ON. I also tried (1<<30), but no luck. sorry the operator is suppose to be (1<<(14+16)). Yes, I tried break on GPIOB->BSRR = (1<<14); no luck. I took the delay function from an example, I also tried delaying with for loop. I dont know what I'm missing.

Comment: It is a poor example.  You should use SYSTICK, or at least declare `time` `volatile`: `void Delay (volatile uint32_t time)`

Comment: You have included the HAL but not used it (or initialised it).  The HAL has a delay function BTW.  Although personally I'd avoid the HAL - not ST's finest offering.  Here you only need "stm32l4xx.h"

Comment: You should never use `1<<` in C. In your case `1<<31` would invoke undefined behavior. Always use `1u <<`.

Answer (score 2):

I was up to write `01` to `GPIOB->MODER [29:28]`.

So I've added

```
GPIOB->MODER &= ~(1<<29);
```

before

```
GPIOB->MODER |= (1<<28);
```

This solves my problem.

Btw: in my code a for loop works better for a delay than the `delay(...)` function.